# sed search multiple strings and output each string and its following string to a separate line

Tags: string, perl, sed

For example; 
I have a long file which contains:

```
Somestring anotherstring -xone xcont othertring -yone ycont againother \
-detail "detail Contents within quote" stuff morestuff .. 

Somestring anotherstring -xone xcont othertring -yone ycont againother \
morestrings -detail detailCont morestrings etc.. ..
```

The desired out:

```
-xone xcont
-ycont ycont
-detail "detail Contents withing quote"
```

Would be ideal to have a csv file with:

```
xone yone detail
xcont ycont "detail Contents within quote"
```

What is the best approach to get the desired output? I have been trying with sed commands with very limited sucess. I am new to perl so didnt get far there either.. Please explain the suggested solution. 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  What identifies the lines that you're interested in?  Is it lines starting 'Somestring anotherstring'?  What is the information you are after?  All options such as `-xone` and `-detail` found on the matching line or on the next line?  And the output is just the 'keys' such as `-xone` and the values such as `xcont`?  Handling double-quoted strings complicates things — what are the rules for escaping embedded double quotes?  Is the list of 'keys' fixed at just the three shown (`-xone`, `-xcont` and `-detail`) or could it be any dash+name string?

Comment: The strings I am interested in have preceding '-' and the information following is what I am after. Unfortunately each line is different; some long, some short. Yes, the key pairs I am interested is: -xone xcont
-ycont ycont
-detail "detail Contents withing quote"

Comment: OK: just to check.  You're looking for any string `-xone` and the following string, or `-yone` and the following string, or `-detail` and the following double quoted string, where there is no need to worry about embedded double quotes.  Further, these entries should all three be found on pairs of adjacent lines, and the group printed together.  Ideally, the output format should be CSV (or do you want tab-separated values, TSV, or some other formatting scheme?).

Comment: I am getting sophomoric errors I cant figure out: This is what I have done: #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
my $regex = qr/-(?<rulename|ruletype|description>\w+) \s+ (?: (?<(\s+\S+\s+)>\w+) | "(?<description\s+>[^"]+)" )/x;
while (<>) {
  while (/$regex/g) {
    say qq($+{key}: "$+{val}");
  }
}
Where/how could I readin the file that contains that data being searched? I am getting two different errors: Sequence (?<r...) not recognized in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/-(?<r <-- HERE ulename|rule and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem consists of two parts:

1. How to match the tags
2. How to output them in an orderly fashion.

The matching part is quite simple, using a regex. Each tag is a hyphen-minus followed by some word characters. As a regex pattern: `-\w+`.

The value seems to either be a word (which we can match like `\w+`) or a quoted string. Assuming this string cannot contain its delimiter, we can use `"[^"]+"` where `[^"]` is a negated character class that matches anything *but* the double quote character.

How do we combine this? With an alternation, and named captures:

```
# I'll answer with Perl
my $regex = qr/-(?<key>\w+) \s+ (?: (?<val>\w+) | "(?<val>[^"]+)" )/x;
```

After that, `$+{key}` contains the key, and `$+{val}` the value for that tag. We can now extract all tags in a line. Given the input

```
Somestring anotherstring -xone xcont othertring -yone ycont againother \-detail "detail Contents within quote" stuff morestuff .. 
Somestring anotherstring -xone xcont othertring -yone ycont againother \morestrings -detail detailCont morestrings etc.. ..
```

And the code

```
use strict; use warnings; use feature 'say';
my $regex = ...;
while (<>) {
  while (/$regex/g) {
    say qq($+{key}: "$+{val}");
  }
}
```

we get the output

```
xone: "xcont"
yone: "ycont"
detail: "detail Contents within quote"
xone: "xcont"
yone: "ycont"
detail: "detailCont"
```

To print that out in a tabular format, we have to collect the data in a certain structure. I will assume that each tag can occur once for each line. Then we can use a hash to define the mapping from tags to their values. We collect these hashes in an array, one for each line. We must also collect the names of all headers, in case one line does not contain all headers. Now our code changes to:

```
use strict; use warnings; use feature 'say';
my $regex = ...;
my %headers;
my @rows;
while (<>) {
  my %tags;
  while (/$regex/g) {
    $tags{$+{key}} = $+{val};
  }
  push @rows, \%tags;
  @headers{keys %tags} = ();  # define the headers
}
```

Now how do we print the data out? We could just dump them as tab separated values:

```
my @headers = keys %headers;
say join "\t", map qq("$_"), @headers;
say join "\t", map qq("$_"), @$_{@headers} for @rows;
```

Output:

```
"yone"  "detail"        "xone"
"ycont" "detail Contents within quote"  "xcont"
"ycont" "detailCont"    "xcont"
```

Oh, and the order of columns is random. We can do better if we use the `Text::CSV` module. Then:

```
use Text::CSV;

my @headers = keys %headers;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ eol => "\n" });
$csv->print(\*STDOUT, \@headers);
$csv->print(\*STDOUT, [@$_{@headers}]) for @rows;
```

And we get the output:

```
yone,xone,detail
ycont,xcont,"detail Contents within quote"
ycont,xcont,detailCont
```

The order of the columns is still random, but this could be fixed through sorting.

You can read through the [`Text::CSV` documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV) to discover many options how you could tweak the output.

Comment: You are super helpful!. I really do appreciate it!. The only known variables here are the keys (-xone, yone, and -detail) NOTE: these all will have the - preceding them. Their values are unknown to me..

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/-(xone|yone|detail)/!d;s//\n\1/;s/[^\n]*\n//;s/\S+\s+("[^"]*"|\S+)/&\n/;P;D' file
```

This looks for lines containing the string `-xone`, `-yone` or `-detail` and prints only them and the following words enclosed by `"`'s or another word.

Comment: Thanks!. I am getting the following error:  sed: -e expression #1, char 35: unknown command: `;'